# Java-Doc dynamic comment

Tags: java, comments, javadoc

does anybody know if its possible to make javadoc with multiple liks to methods like:

```
{@linkplain MyClass#get*}
```

so every method in class which matches the "regex" get* will be shown in the java doc.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to do that because javadoc is not compiled.